# Automatic reopening file for reading if it was recreated

Tags: ruby, file-io, tail

There is some (compiled and not my) program **A**, which starts .log file from the beginning each time, when I launch it. And I wrote the program **B** to work with this log using this approach:

```
File.open("qconsole.log") do |log|
    log.gets nil # I am interested only in new lines
    loop do
        next sleep 0.1 unless line = log.gets
        line.chomp!
        puts line
        # some code
    end
end
```

For example, after two new lines in the .log file I see this output:

```
 player1: i talk blabla
 player2: no way!
```

But when I quit and restart the program **A**:

```
]\quit 
----- Server Shutdown -----
==== ShutdownGame ====
AAS shutdown.
---------------------------
----- CL_Shutdown -----
RE_Shutdown( 1 )
Shutting down OpenGL subsystem
...wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL ): success
...deleting GL context: success
...releasing DC: success
...destroying window
...shutting down QGL
...unloading OpenGL DLL
-----------------------
```

the program **B** seems to lose the .log file after this. It doesn't print me new lines anymore. I suppose, it gets eternal `nil` from `log.gets`.

So how can I know, that I need to stop doing `log.gets` and reopen the .log file?

UPD: Windows 7

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a loop itself.

Comment: @Linuxios, checked, the loop from my code doesn't stop, break or anything. It still loops.

Comment: That's odd... Are you sure you restart the server?

Comment: @Linuxios, yes, even killed the process of **A**.

Answer (score 0):

My current **dirty** solution:

```
logfilesize = File.stat(logfile).size
log = File.open logfile
log.gets nil

loop do
    logfilesize = File.stat(logfile).size.tap{ |t|
        if t < logfilesize
            log.close
            log = File.open logfile
        end
    }
    next sleep 0.1 unless line = log.gets
    line.chomp!
    puts line
    # some code
end
```